# Data not being displayed from Mysql DB

Tags: php, mysql

I got this wonderful array structure from Webtecher, however I am battling to get the values from the DB into the array to have them as selected.

```
<?php 
$a=array("","2","5","10","20","30","45","60","90","120");
$tsel = 3;  
$tempo = PageDB::getInstance()->get_tempo_by_page_id($pageID);
            echo  '<label style="padding-right:28px;">Tempo</label>
                <select name="tempo">';
for($i=1;$i<sizeof($a);$i++)
{echo '<option value="'.$i.'" '.($tsel==$i?'selected':'').'>'.$a[$i].' Sec</option>';if($tsel==$i)$a[0]=$tsel;}
echo '</select>';?>
```

How my page info is called and displayed is through these queries and statements:

```
 if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
    $page = array("pid" => $_POST['pageID'],
    "message_text" => $_POST['message_text'],
    "message" => $_POST['message'],
    "is_centered" => $_POST['is_centered'],
    "inverted" => $_POST['inverted'],
    "show_time" => $_POST['show_time'],
    "show_temp" => $_POST['show_temp'],
    "tempo" => $_POST['tempo'],
    "transition" => $_POST['transition'],
    "sunday" => $_POST['sunday'],
    "monday" => $_POST['monday'],
    "tuesday" => $_POST['tuesday'],
    "wednesday" => $_POST['wednesday'],
    "thursday" => $_POST['thursday'],
    "friday" => $_POST['friday'],
    "saturday" => $_POST['saturday'],
    "start_date" => $_POST['start_date'],
    "end_date" => $_POST['end_date'],
    "start_time" => $_POST['start_time'],
    "end_time" => $_POST['end_time'],   
    "campaignid" => $_POST['campaignid']);
    else if (array_key_exists('pageID', $_GET)) {
        $page = mysqli_fetch_array (PageDB::getInstance()->get_page_by_page_id($_GET['pageID']));
    } else
        $page = array(
        "pid"=>"",
        "message_text" => "",
        "message" => "",
        "is_centered" => "",
        "inverted" => "",
        "show_time" => "",
        "show_temp" => "",
        "tempo" => "",
        "transition" => "", 
        "sunday" =>"",
        "monday" =>"",
        "tuesday" =>"",
        "wednesday" =>"",
        "thursday" =>"",
        "friday" =>"",
        "saturday" =>"",
        "start_date" => "",
        "end_date" => "",
        "start_time" => "",
        "end_time" => "");
```

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_array (` I'm also wondering at the space here...

Comment: Is the second if-condition, with the mysqli_fetch instruction, being executed?  you could check this by putting an error_log('...') message in it and check php_errors.log after you run the script.

Comment: It's not being executed ... but I have no idea as to why :-(

Comment: Have you got register_globals set to true in your php.ini? I think more recent versions of PHP don't create the $_POST and $_GET superglobals by default.

Comment: Ok, I've set register_globals to true in PHP.ini ... but not much change

Comment: @Mike: superglobals `$_GET` and `$_POST` are created by default, also in recent versions of PHP. Also when`register_globals` are off. And `register_globals` is evil and dangerous and deprecated, it should be set to off. @user1395580: Please set `register_globals` back to off.

Comment: @user1395580: if your `mysqli_fetch_array()` statement is not executed then either `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"` is true or `array_key_exists('pageID', $_GET)` is false. Or there is another issue in code you are not showing.

Comment: @Arjan: Don't know what I was thinking there :)

Comment: Holy Boby Tables, Batman